# Replace value if null

Tags: sql

I'm not great at SQL so this question should be very easy to answer :) I have a column titled `Grades` and all values are currently `NULL`. I would like to update the `Grades` column to "No Data" if it's `NULL`

This is what I have so far: `Select (ISNULL(Grade, 'test'))
From bleaTest`

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE bleaTest SET Grades = 'No Data' WHERE Grades IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 3):

To update table you can do this

```
UPDATE bleaTest
SET Grade = 'No data'
WHERE Grade is null;
```

And to select

```
Select ISNULL(Grade, 'No Data') Grade From bleaTest
```

Comment: I like COALESCE over ISNULL but that's me.

Comment: I like `ISNULL` over `COALESCE`

Comment: According to this http://blogs.x2line.com/al/archive/2004/03/01/189.aspx ISNULL is minimally faster but I *think* that ISNULL is not in the SQL standard while COALESCE is. Not sure about that though.

Comment: Since the question is not tied to any database, I think the best way to go is **coalesce**, since IsNull is not standard.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following SQL statement

```
UPDATE bleaTest set Grades = 'No Data' WHERE Grades IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

This probably needs to be customized for your setup, but if you actually want to update the table it would look like

```
update theTable
set Grades = isnull(Grade, 'No Data')
```

Or alternately

```
update theTable
set grades = 'no data'
where grades is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do an Update as said before:

```
UPDATE bleaTest SET Grades = 'No Data' WHERE Grades IS NULL;
```

But if you want to prevent new registers to have a NULL value in that column you can use this code to alter the table:

```
ALTER TABLE bleaTest MODIFY Grades NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE bleaTest ALTER  Grades SET DEFAULT 'No Data';
```

the code can chance depending on what database you use.